# Spring portlet Application. Form binding error messages not printed once form reloads

Tags: spring, validation, binding, controller, portlet

I have a nasty validation problem with this annotated Spring controller (relevant parts below):

```
@RequestMapping(value="view")
@SessionAttributes(types = UserChoice.class)
@Controller(value="takeSurveyController")
public class TakeSurveyController {

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Answer.class, new AnswerPropertyEditor(getAnswerService()));
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    @RenderMapping(params="action=showQuestionForUserForm")
    public String showQuestionForUserForm(@RequestParam("surveyID") Long surveyId, 
                     @RequestParam(value="questionID", required=false) Long questionId,
                     RenderRequest request, Model model) {

        // ...

        return "questionForUserShow";
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    @ActionMapping(params="action=submitUserChoice")
    public void submitAnswerForm(@ModelAttribute("userChoice") UserChoice userChoice,
            BindingResult bindingResult, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

        // ...
            getUserChoiceValidator().validate(userChoice, bindingResult);

            if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                getUserChoiceService().save(userChoice);

                // ...
            }
            else {
                // binding errors: reload current question
                response.setRenderParameter("action", "showQuestionForUserForm");
                response.setRenderParameter("surveyID", survey.getId().toString());
                response.setRenderParameter("questionID", currentQuestion.getId().toString());
            }
        // ...
    }

    // ....

}
```

The logic works perfectly. If I have a binding error, the render method is called from the action method and the page reloads.
The problem is I can't get the validation errors printed on the JSP page.

I have a similar controller implementing an add operation (AddQuestionController) and there I get the messages printed.
The differences are that this has a session object (the other doesn't) and the other has a method annotated with @ModelAttribute while this hasn't.

If I remove on the AddQuestionController the @ModelAttribute annotated method, error messages are not printed anymore.
I thought that adding a similar method on this one would solve the problem but it didn't work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround by David Rosell on Jul 1 '11 on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140659/spring-portlet-mvc-validation-fails-during-submission-of-the-editted-form?rq=1) seems to solve the issue.